# Facebook c# SDK posting to my business page

Tags: c#, facebook

I've created 2 apps (one real and one test) to post to my business page

When I use the appId/secret key from my test app,  it does post to my business page under my business account.

When I switch the AppId/secret to my real app,  it does post to my business page but under my facebook username,  not my business page....

It's the same code,  how does switching from an app to another can cause this?

At the end I want to post to my business page and I dont want my personnal name to appear

any insights?!

First I call oauth to authorize my user

```
string FacebookClientId = Util.FbAppId;
    Response.Redirect(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/" +
      "authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope=publish_actions,manage_pages,user_groups",
      FacebookClientId, callbackUrl));
```

Then when I have the "code" in call back url,  I call oauth again to control my facebook business page as my business page

```
var fb = new FacebookClient();
                dynamic result = fb.Post("oauth/access_token", new
                {
                    client_id = Util.FbAppId,
                    client_secret = Util.FbAppSecret,
                    redirect_uri = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri,
                    code = code
                });
```

Comment: It is almost impossible to make any guesses without seeing your actual code.

Comment: I've added the code,  but problem does not seems to be the code.  When I try with my test app,  it does post under my business name,  when i swtich appid/secret to my real app,  it post under my personnal name...

Comment: You should use a page access token and nothing else

Comment: when i get only a page token,  i get the following result when I try to post with app token

From My test app it works...
From my real app it says "message": "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"

Comment: can this have something to do with submission approval process??  my test app is approved while my real app is in pending submission